# DRF, Permissions and Tests: Receiving a 403 running tests, 200 OK in browser

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm continuing my journey of testing my Django Rest Framework application as I add new views and more functionality. I must admit, at this stage, I'm finding testing harder than actually coding and building my app. I feel that there are far fewer resources on testing DRF available than there are resources talking about building a REST framework with DRF. C'est la vie, though, I soldier on.

My issue that I'm currently facing is that I'm receiving a 403 error when testing one of my DRF ViewSets. I can confirm that the view, and its permissions work fine when using the browser or a regular python script to access the endpoint.

Let's start with the model that is used in my ViewSet

```py
class QuizTracking(models.Model):
    case_attempt = models.ForeignKey(CaseAttempt, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Of note here is that there is a FK to a user. This is used when determining permissions.

Here is my test function. I have not included code for the entire class for the sake of brevity.

```py
    def test_question_retrieve(self):
        """
            Check that quiz tracking/ID returns a 200 OK and the content is correct
        """
        jim = User(username='jimmy', password='monkey123', email='jimmy@jim.com')
        jim.save()
        quiz_tracking = QuizTracking(answer=self.answer, case_attempt=self.case_attempt, user=jim)
        quiz_tracking.save()
        request = self.factory.get(f'/api/v1/progress/quiz-tracking/{quiz_tracking.id}')

        # How do I refernce my custom permission using Permission.objects.get() ?
        # permission = Permission.objects.get()
        # jim.user_permissions.add(permission)

        self.test_user.refresh_from_db()
        force_authenticate(request, user=jim)
        response = self.quiz_detail_view(request, pk=quiz_tracking.id)
        print(response.data)
        print(jim.id)
        print(quiz_tracking.user.id)

        self.assertContains(response, 'answer')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In the above code, I define a user, `jim` and a `quiz_tracking` object owned by `jim`.

I build my request, `force_authenticate` the requst and the execute my request and store the response in `response`.

The interesting things to note here are:
- jim.id and quiz_tracking.user.id are the same value
- I receive a 403 response with

```
{'detail': ErrorDetail(string='You do not have permission to perform this action.', code='permission_denied')}
```

You may have noticed that I have commented out `permission = Permission.objects.get()` My understanding is that I need to pass this my Permission Class, which in my case is `IsUser`. However, there is no record of this in my DB and hence `Permission.objects.get('IsUSer')` call fails.

So my questions are as follows:
- How do I authenticate my request so that I receive a 200 OK?
- Do I need to add a permission to my user in my tests, and if so, which permission and with what syntax?

Below is my view and below that is my custom permission file defining `IsUser`

```py
class QuickTrackingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = QuizTrackingSerializser

    def get_queryset(self):
        return QuizTracking.objects.all().filter(user=self.request.user)

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            self.permission_classes = [IsUser, ]
        elif self.action == 'retrieve':
            self.permission_classes = [IsUser, ]

        return super(self.__class__, self).get_permissions()
```

**N.B.** If I comment out `def get_permissions()`, then my test passes without problem.

My custom `permission.py`

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class IsSuperUser(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_superuser


class IsUser(BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.user:
            if request.user.is_superuser:
                return True
            else:
                return obj == request.user
        else:
            return False
```

Cheers,

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is your permission `IsUser`.

You compare `QuizTracking` instance with user instance.

change this line

```
return obj == request.user
```

to

```
return obj.user.id == request.user.id
```

*One off topic suggestion*

You can write your `IsUser` class in the following way which is easier to read

```
class IsUser(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user.is_superuser or obj.user.id == request.user.id
```

Note that `has_object_permission` is only called if the view level `has_permission` returns True.

Comment: @anowlinorbit no worries. added one "codereview" comment:-)